# Run a macro after saving excel-file won't work

Tags: excel, vba, after-save

I can't get my macro running in `AfterSave` or `BeforeClose` event.

I export one sheet to a .csv file, that's already working well with the next code when I link this macro to a button:

```
Sub CopyToCSV()

Worksheets("LastLots").UsedRange.Rows("1:5").Calculate
ThisWorkbook.Save
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFileName As String
  'The path and file names:
MyPath = "D:\Data\PW\2018\"
MyFileName = "LastLots-exported"
  'Makes sure the path name ends with "\":
If Not Right(MyPath, 1) = "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
  'Makes sure the filename ends with ".csv"
If Not Right(MyFileName, 4) = ".csv" Then MyFileName = MyFileName & ".csv"
  'Copies the sheet to a new workbook:
Sheets("LastLots").Copy
  'The new workbook becomes Activeworkbook:
With ActiveWorkbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'Saves the new workbook to given folder / filename:
    .SaveAs Filename:= _
        MyPath & MyFileName, _
        FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
        CreateBackup:=False
  'Closes the file
    .Close False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End With
End Sub
```

The code above is in a module. As I said, when linked to a button and press that button, it works very well.
But I want it running when the user saved the file.
Fot this, I put the next code in `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean) 
If Success = True Then
Call CopyToCSV
End If 
End Sub
```

I tried various things, like putting the code of the macro inside the `AfterSave`-event, and disable/enable `Application.EnableEvents` before and after calling `CopyToCSV` but nothing works for me...

Does anyone have a suggestion? I'm out of mind, and every topic I find on Google say to put the code in `ThisWorkbook`, but already done that.

Comment: You have `ThisWorkbook.Save` in your sub so you definitely need to disable events before calling `CopyToCSV`.  It's possible you somehow disabled events without re-enabling them, so to make sure enter `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the immediate pane of the VB editor and hit Enter - that will re-enable events and allow your AfterSave event to fire.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for this solution! I removed the `ThisWorkbook.Save` from the sub. It was a little unneccesary, because of my `AfterSave` event.

Answer (score 1):

Just typing the code somewhere does not make it an event handler.

You must enter "ThisWorkbook", look at the top bar, select "ThisWorkbook" and the desired event.

Excel will then automatically create the empty Sub for you, associated with the event. You insert your code inside that Sub.

[image]

More details: https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/code-modules-event-procedures/

---

Hints: before any `if`, test if the script is being run, add a message such as `MsgBox "After save!!!"`

This will help you identify if the problem is the event not being called or your code not being run properly.

Comment: You *can* just type the code (or copy/paste from SO), as long as you get it right...